# How can you make customized downloadable reports in r shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, report, shinydashboard

So basically, my app has 10 different tables and graphs being generated for the user as results. Now, what I want to do is, display a checklist for the user and then ask the user to select the items they want to include in their downloaded report. This will make a customized report which will only include the things the user wishes to have. So, please help me out with the process of adding items into a report only if a checkbox is checked. I, kind of, have got the idea that I will have to generate the report with r-markdown but would love to have some clarity on it further.

**app.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(rmarkdown)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$downloadReport <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste('my-report', sep = '.', switch(
        input$format, PDF = 'pdf', HTML = 'html', Word = 'docx'
      ))
    },
    content = function(file) {
      src <- normalizePath('test.Rmd')
      
      # temporarily switch to the temp dir, in case you do not have write
      # permission to the current working directory
      owd <- setwd(tempdir())
      on.exit(setwd(owd))
      file.copy(src, 'test.Rmd', overwrite = TRUE)
      
      out <- rmarkdown::render('test.Rmd',
                               params = list(text = input$text,outp=input$Try),
                               switch(input$format,
                                      PDF = pdf_document(), 
                                      HTML = html_document(), 
                                      Word = word_document()
                               ))
      file.rename(out, file)
    }
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$textarea(id="text", rows=20, cols=155, 
                placeholder="Some placeholder text"),
  
  flowLayout(radioButtons('format', 'Document format', c('HTML', 'Word'),
                          inline = TRUE),
             checkboxGroupInput("Try","Let's hope this works",choiceNames = list("include hi","include hey","include hello","include how are you"),choiceValues = list("HI","HEY","HELLO","HOW ARE YOU")),
             downloadButton('downloadReport'))
  
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**test.Rmd**

```
---
title: "Parameterized Report for Shiny"
output: html_document
params:
  text: 'NULL'
  outp: 'NULL'
---

# Some title

`r params[["text"]]`
`r params[["outp"]]`
```

In this, I have added the  checkboxGroupInput with id "Try" and I get the value of it as output. So, I am halfway there except now, I just need to get plots as output instead of choicevalues.

Comment: What have you tried? Please share some code.

Comment: I have now added a sample code snippet. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks good. Just pass the data over as an argument and create plots as you would in your Shiny App. You can use the default plot function, but also `ggplot2` or `plotly`. To include/exclude plots/tables, also pass the checkbox value `input$Try` as parameter to the report and use conditions to add plots/tables as shown below.

I only post the Rmd and the lines I changed in your Shiny App. Everything else looks good.

```
server <- function(input, output) {
    output$downloadReport <- downloadHandler(
        filename = function() {
            paste('my-report', sep = '.', switch(
                input$format, PDF = 'pdf', HTML = 'html', Word = 'docx'
            ))
        },
        content = function(file) {
            src <- normalizePath('test.Rmd')
            # temporarily switch to the temp dir, in case you do not have write
            # permission to the current working directory
            owd <- setwd(tempdir())
            on.exit(setwd(owd))
            file.copy(src, 'test.Rmd', overwrite = TRUE)
            
            include <- input$Try
            out <- rmarkdown::render('test.Rmd',
                                     params = list(tbl = mtcars, include = include),
                                     switch(input$format,
                                            PDF = pdf_document(), 
                                            HTML = html_document(), 
                                            Word = word_document()
                                     ))
            file.rename(out, file)
        }
    )
}
```

Updated r markdown:

````
---
title: "Parameterized Report for Shiny"
output: html_document
params:
  tbl: NA
  include: NA
---

```{r echo=FALSE}
library(knitr)
tbl <- params$tbl
include <- params$include
```

```{r echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
if ('HI' %in% include) {
    kable(tbl[1:5,], caption= 'A table')
}
```

```{r echo=FALSE, result='asis'}
if ('HEY' %in% include) {
    plot(tbl$mpg, tbl$cyl)
}
```
````

What I really like is that you don't have to restart the Shiny App every time you change the report, as it is independent of the app itself.

Comment: Thanks Tom for your answer but I would like to know how I can make this conditional. Like, for example, if the user desires to have only a table in the report, then they will just check that checkbox and the report will consist of the desired output.
It is basically a conditional knitting of report I wish to have where only if a checkbox value is true, that part of the report should be included.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I updated the code accordingly.

Comment: Just an extension to this question. Do you think it is possible to show the user all the things available for download in a consolidated way on the shiny tab and then he/she can select if that should be downloaded

Comment: Many things are possible :-). Take a look at the shinydashboard package. I like to structure things using the box function.

Comment: Yes, I am using the shiny dashboard package. My question was whether we could display as well as download the selected item together. For example, we show two tables on the screen and once the user checks the option "Include Table 1", the first table is included in the report.